# class Edge List c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, graph

I'm trying to make the Edge List class on c++. 
When I compile the code, I get a lot of errors, but I can not understand, what do I wrong?

```
struct vertex
{
   double x,y;
};

class EdgeList
{
private:
    std::map<vertex, vector<vertex>> graph_container;
public:

    void add_vertex(const vertex& v) { //add a vertex to the map
        graph_container.insert(pair<vertex,vector<vertex> >(v, vector<vertex>()));
    }
    //*
    void add_edge(const vertex& v, const vertex& u) { //look up vertex in map 
            auto it = graph_container.find(v);
            if (it != graph_container.end())
                *it.push_back(u);

    }    
    //*/
 };
```

The first error is

```
64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from EarTr.cpp:1:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/includ
e/c++/bits/stl_function.h:387:20: note:   'const vertex' is not derived from 'co
nst std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
       { return __x < __y; }
```

Comment: When posting question about build errors then please include the actual errors you get. Complete, in full and including possible informational notes. Just copy-paste the text (*as text*) into the question body. Then mark the source (which should preferably be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) with comments where the errors are.

Comment: But you should probably start by learning about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The expression `*it.push_back(u)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

I've added 2 functions to the struct

```
bool operator==(const vertex &o)const {
    return x == o.x && y == o.y;
}

bool operator<(const vertex &o) const{
    return x < o.x || (x == o.x && y < o.y);
}
```

So, now the map can work with my type of data.
Also I use

```
it->second.push_back(u);
```

instead of

```
*it.push_back(u);
```